# AzureAD get user breakdown based on roles using REST API

Tags: javascript, azure-active-directory

Web application uses AzureAD as usermanagement. Now there is a need to get a breakdown of users based on roles. I have found that atleast in Powershell people have created some complex queries to get it. But is this possible through the Rest API?

Expected result would be something like

```
admin: 5
signer: 20
executive: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

> Now there is a need to get a breakdown of users based on roles. I have found that atleast in Powershell people have created some complex queries to get it. But is this possible through the Rest API?

Unfortunately, in order to get the role Assignments for individual users in Azure via Rest API, requires you to call the Rest API **multiple** times,

To list the **role Assignments** with object type as user or service principal and the role definition ID assigned to them, you can make use of below API call:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscriptionID>/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments?api-version=2022-04-01
```

[image]

You can use below API call to get the **Role definition** list, which lists all the roles and name of the roles based on the above role definition ID:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscriptionID>/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions?api-version=2022-04-01
```

[image]

To get the **User details** you need to call below MS graph endpoint :-

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<principalID>
```

[image]

If you want to get the role assignments of **specific** user, you can get that by filtering the Object ID of that user in the API call like below:-

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscriptionID>/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments?api-version=2022-04-01&$filter=atScope() and assignedTO('principalID')
```

[image]

> You cannot merge the results of all these API calls in any tool or
> unless you do it programmatically or via a script.

Thus, I used PowerShell script to get the desired output like below: -

**PowerShell Script** :-

```
$Roleassignments=(Get-AzADUser).UserPrincipalname | % { Get-AzRoleAssignment -SignInName $_ | Select-Object DisplayName,RoleDefinitionName,Scope}  
$a=$Roleassignments.RoleDefinitionName | Sort-Object | Get-Unique  
foreach($role in $a)  
{  
Write-host $role ":" $role.count  
}
```

**Result** :-

[image]